# How to enable content security policy in web api angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, content-security-policy

I  want to ***enable content security policy for my web api which is used for my angular application***.

I have seen some references and added the following code in the web config.

But still I can load my files through iframe tag in w3schools. It does not through any exception like ***frame-ancestors 'none'***.
Do I need to add any code in web api other than this? Or still web config will handle all the request?

> ***Note***: When requesting web api calls, I am not appending the domain and host for each calls when requesting web api methods.
>
> For example,
>
> $http.get("/api/user/updateuser"). Do I need to append for each call?
>   Is that necessary?

The following code I have added in web config

```
  <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="ALLOW-FROM http://localhost:4086" />
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors http://localhost:4086" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>

  </system.webServer>
```

I am getting the following response header

[image: I am getting the following response header]

**Rerence : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options**

Comment: Have you checked whether the CSP header is actually present in the response headers?

Comment: If clean the solution and rebuild the solution, this works. May be issue from the vs.